# Ansible collections in docker container not being picked up

Tags: docker, ansible, ansible-collections

I've got a 2.9.13 ansible container running. I install a few collection in the container and they end up in:

`./root/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/<namespace>/<collection>`

When I run the playbook from a folder in my home directory I get role cannot be found.

```
ERROR! the role 'tower-verify' was not found in <namespace>.<collection>:redhat_cop.tower_configuration:ansible.tower:ansible.legacy:/home/<playbook>/roles:/root/.ansible/roles:/usr/share/ansible/roles:/etc/ansible/roles:/home/<playbook>
```

It seems to check the collection but cannot find it.

```
root@1a3f9e1234c5:~/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/<namespace>/<collection>/roles# ls
tower-verify
```

I have the following sections in the playbook code:

```
  collections:
    - <namespace>.<collection>
    - redhat_cop.tower_configuration
    - ansible.tower

  roles:
    - {role: tower-verify, tags: tower_verify}
```

ansible.cfg entry:

```
# Install collections into [current dir]/ansible_collections/namespace/collections_name
collections_paths = ./
```

So is ansible really checking that location?

Thanks for any assistance ahead of time.

Comment: For the time being I dropped the collections under the playbook project in a collections folder.

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I dropped the collections under the playbook project in a collections folder.